# Using Sugar ORM when also using singleton application class

Tags: orm

I have extended the Android.Application class so that I can keep state (using the application as the singleton).

However, I now want to use the Sugar ORM library to simplify my DB access, but the Sugar docs (http://satyan.github.io/sugar/getting-started.html) require that  I specify 'SugarApp' as my application class in AndroidManifest.xml.

Which clashes with my Application class that extends Android Application.

**Is there an alternative approach?**

From the Sugar docs:

E.g. by changing the android:name attribute of the application tag.

```
<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/icon"
android:name="com.orm.SugarApp">
.
.
<meta-data android:name="DATABASE" android:value="sugar_example.db" />
<meta-data android:name="VERSION" android:value="2" />
<meta-data android:name="QUERY_LOG" android:value="true" />
<meta-data android:name="DOMAIN_PACKAGE_NAME" android:value="com.example" />
.
.
</application>
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Answering my own question -tut tut ;-)

It's simple, I just changed my Custom App class to extend SugarApp instead of Android.Application, as SugarApp itself extends android app!

Comment: Make sure android:name=".MyApplication" instead of android:name="com.orm.SugarApp" in AndroidManifest

Comment: That worked for me! However, suddenly my unittests failed.
A solution for this can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27964666/testing-with-sugarorm-and-robolectric/44421666#44421666):
However, the accepted answer doesn't include a custom App class, so please check out my additional answer.

Answer (score 10):

If you take a look at SugarApp class, you will find that it extends Application class overriding the onCreate() & onTerminate() methods doing its scaffolding:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SugarContext.init(this);
}

@Override
public void onTerminate() {
    super.onTerminate();
    SugarContext.terminate();
}
```

The only thing you have to do if you want to keep your base application class is to add those method calls to your custom class.

In this way, you can maintain your custom application class instead of extending SugarApp class.

Comment: Nice alternative to the accepted answer, sure it will help other readers. thanks